# How to color specific region of plot. SageMath

Tags: python, sage

[image]

I am starting a project involving Continued Fractions on Hecke triangle surfaces and I would like to color the area over the half circle and between the two vertical lines. How could I do it using sagemath python?

```
from sage.plot.line import Line
var('x')
e = sqrt(1-x^2)
f = line([(-1/2, sqrt(3)/2), (-1/2, 3)])
g = line([(1/2, sqrt(3)/2), (1/2, 3)])

show(plot(e) + g + f, aspect_ratio=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used region_plot and delimited the area over the half circle and between the lines.

```
t = region_plot( y > sqrt(1-x^2), (x,-1/2,1/2), (y,-2,3), incol='red', 
bordercol='gray')
show(plot(e) + g + f + t, aspect_ratio=1)
```

Comment: Add comments explaining your answer to those that read this later.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer